# How to filter a list based on another list most efficiently? Ideally with a vectorised approach

Tags: python-3.x, list, filter, vectorization

I have two lists:

```
a = [25,12,91,37,10,11,19,20,99,101]
b = [0,1,1,2,0,0,0,1,2,1]
```

I want to filter list a with reference to the element at the equivalent position in list b to return three separate lists as follows:

```
0: [25,10,11,10]
1: [12,91,20,101]
2: [37,99]
```

I have looked into using compress from itertools, but this seems to be designed only for the instance where list b would be boolean.

One solution using a foor loop is:

```
lst_dct = {k:[] for k in set(b)}

for elem1,elem2 in zip(a,b):

    lst_dct[elem2].append(elem1)

lst_dct
>>> {0: [25, 10, 11, 19], 1: [12, 91, 20, 101], 2: [37, 99]}
```

Timing this gives:

```
1.95 µs ± 145 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Another using a dataframe is:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.concat([pd.Series(a,name='a'),pd.Series(b,name='b')],axis=1)

lst_dct = {k:[] for k in set(df.b)}

for elem in set(df.b):

    lst_dct[elem] = list(df.a.where(df.b == elem).dropna())

lst_dct
>>> {0: [25.0, 10.0, 11.0, 19.0], 1: [12.0, 91.0, 20.0, 101.0], 2: [37.0, 99.0]}
```

Timing this gives:

```
3.29 ms ± 399 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The first solution seems more pythonic, less cumbersome and much faster.

However, I am interested to find if there is a more pythonic i.e. more elegant with no for loop and deploying vectorisation that I suspect would also be faster.

Thanks!

Comment: What you're asking for is like a "keyhole optimization"...looking only at a very tiny part of what must be a much larger data pipeline.  An efficient approach must incorporate knowledge missing here, like where the data is coming from and going to.  For example if the source data is already in NumPy arrays because of some prior step, that is much different to having it in lists.  Also, it's impossible to make an optimal solution without knowing the amount of data.  Your list solution will win for small inputs but likely deteriorate for larger ones...but how large are your real data?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Ok for detail it will be data originally extracted from a dataframe that I suspected makes sense to switch to either a numpy array or a list (at the moment I actually have a coming in as a pandas series and b as a numpy array, but simplified the case both to lists here).  Data elements in each object will be in the region of 10,000, but an important point is I will be performing expanding calcuations on this data over and over incorporating the above code.  So small savings here are bigger overall.  Also, I am interested in a vectorised approach in any case.

Comment: A vectorized approach is quite difficult to use here because the output is jagged, not rectangular.  The best way to speed this code up is probably Numba.